# Generic Exception handling in jsf 2 and spring webflow

Tags: jsf-2, exception, spring-webflow

I am trying to implement exception handling in our application (primefaces,jsf and spring webflow). I have used **FlowExecutionExceptionHandler** and this works for some exceptions like **ActionExecutionException** (able to redirect to error page in this scenario). Not for all the other exceptions. I need to redirect the user to error page (outside flow) on exceptions and timeout page on session time-out. I have observed that **FlowExecutionExceptionHandler** is not getting called when exception happens in **actionListener** call and jsf related exceptions.
Can somebody suggest me the implementation to fit for the above said scenarios.

Answer (score 0):

try using global transitions:

```
    <!-- your view-states -->

    <!-- errors-pages -->
    <view-state id="defaultError" view="/WEB-INF/errors/defaultError.jsp"/>

    <global-transitions>
        <transition on-exception="java.lang.Exception" to="defaultError"/>
    </global-transitions>
</flow>
```